# How do I populate combobox lists from arrays in sequence

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox

I have a userform that has several combo boxes with lists.  These lists are to be fed from several dynamic arrays on a worksheet.  I know how to fill one combobox with the array but I would like to fill each with their respective information from the arrays.  I have the code to load one but I am thinking that if I were to re-write the code for each then the code would be very slow and tedious.  Can you tell how to more effectively do this?
[image]

```
The code to fill the Device Brand/Model combobox is as follows:

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim machbrandmod As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Arrays")

For Each machbrandmod In ws.Range("mach_type")
Me.nd_mod_cb.AddItem machbrandmod.Value
Next machbrandmod

End Sub
```

[image]

Do I have to exit sub, define the next Dim, and then rewrite the code for the next combobox?  Or is there a more efficient way?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Does your "mach_type" named range have only a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your ranges looks like in your picture, meaning some rows of the same column (something like "A2:A6"), a simple solution will be the next:

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = ws.Range("mach_type").value: Me.nd_mod_cb.list = arr
```

If your range has only a row and more columns (something like "A1:E1") you can use:

```
 arr = ws.Range("mach_type").value: Me.nd_mod_cb.list = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
```

Comment: I don't know if I explained correctly, each one of the combo boxes has an array that feeds it. I want each combobox to be fed the list from the array at "form initialize".

Comment: @D Brown: How do you obtain that specific arrays? Are they 1D or 2D arrays? What I presented in the above code, are arrays directly obtained from the worksheet ranges and able to be loaded directly in the combo, using its `list` property...

Comment: @D Brown: I can see in your code `ws.Range("mach_type")`. Isn't it a named range? If yes, can you post here the range address? Something like "A2:A6", like it can be supposed looking to the attached picture. But, maybe it is different. So, can you post here its address?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not explaining right.  I am new to VBA and trying.  They are all 1D arrays.    For example the addess for the array that feeds nd_mach_tp_cb is on the arrays worksheet in an array called mach_type(I made it dynamic using Offset... here is what I used =OFFSET(Arrays!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Arrays!$A:$A)-1,1).  All of the arrays that I want feeding each comobox are setup the same except for the column address.

Comment: OK. Can you explain what "mach_type" is? If it is a named range, you ca simply use `MsgBox ws.Range("mach_type").Address`. Please, post here what that code line returns.

Comment: @D Brown: Did you simple test the (first) code? I mean, replace your `For Each ... Next` loop with: `Dim arr As Variant`, on the next row `arr = ws.Range("mach_type").value` and on the following `Me.nd_mod_cb.list = arr`. Run, please, the code. Does it what you need?

Comment: To answer your first question mach_type is the name that I gave the array.  I will run the code this morning and have you an answer.

Comment: I just ran the code as you wrote it and received a 424 Runtime error Object Required.

Comment: It worked perfectly!!!  Thank you.  Sorry I am learning as I go.  So once I write the information from the userform to the table, I will clear all of the fields and then I have to reload each combobox with the lists...I can still use this method correct?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. You can used the same `arr` variable, loading it with your specific ranges. If you would name your combo boxes in an efficient way (let us say `"cb_mach_type"` for the one in discussion) we can imagine a better/shorter way of loading your combo. I mean, creating an array with all your names and then to iterate between form controls and load the ones which the appropriate array. .. I can show you how, but when a piece of code answered your question, we here have the habit to tick the left code check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. ..

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    FillList "mach_type", Me.nd_mod_cb
    FillList "other_list", Me.other_cb
    'etc

End Sub

Sub FillList(rangeName as String, lst As Object)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Worksheets("Arrays").Range(rangeName).Cells
        lst.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if I explained correctly, each one of the combo boxes has an array that feeds it.  I want each combobox to be fed the list from the array at "form initialize".

Comment: Did you try FaneDuru's first example?  That seems like exactly what you want.  You have to write *some* code...